# is it a must to use a semi-colon after an object literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, syntax, destructuring

is it a must to use semicolons after an object literal in js?

this code doesnot work:

```
          let nameof = "Hey";
          let age = 12
           const obj = {
           nameof: "One",
           age: 12,
           order: function () {
           return this.name;
            },
        }
           ({ nameof, age } = obj);
          console.log(nameof, age)
```

yet this works when a semi-colon is added at the end of the object literal.

Comment: It is always recommended to add semicolons, to prevent errors like these.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is needed, otherwise the browser issues this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'obj' before
> initialization (line 10)

Moreover, my IDE says:

> The expression is not callable. If this is not supposed to be a call,
> check for a missing semicolon